# How to resolve LNK2001

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, compiler-errors, lnk2001

I have a set of code written in VS 6. I am trying to write a CLI wrapper for that in VS 2008. I included one of the VS6 header files in the CLI code and compiled. 
 While compiling I am getting
 `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Someclass::SomeMethod(SomeObject& os)`. 
 When I searched for the method and the class in the error it correponds to the code,

Header File.

```
class SomeClass: public ParentClass
 {
  virtual void SomeMethod(SomeObject& os);
}
```

CPP File

```
void SomeClass::SomeMethod(SomeObject& os)
{
//Implementation here
}
```

SomeMethod is actually overridden from the ParentClass

When I make the declaration in the header file by adding a open and close curly braces as

```
virtual void SomeMethod(SomeObject& os) {};
```

the error disappears. But I cannot do that since it would result in one method having two bodies. Why is this behavior? How do I overcome this? Or Do I have to put any #pragma while including BS6 headers in CLI?

Comment: Are there templates involved?  Because that changes everything.  I'd assume not, but thought I'd make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've not included 'CPP File' in your project. That would also explain why you don't get an error when you have two bodies. To check this try putting a deliberate compile error in CPP File. If the compiler doesn't complain that would prove that you aren't compiling CPP File.

Comment: Yes I didn't. I didn know that I need to include that. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any other way so that I need not include those CPP files?

Comment: A very strange question. What do you mean by 'include'? You definitely should not be doing this `#include "file.cpp"` but you should be telling your compiler to compile your code. I can't imagine why you would think you don't need to do this. You probably need to explain yourself a bit more, there's something here I'm not understanding.

Comment: I didn mean #include. Ok, anyway. Lets forget it.